# Concatenate dataframes in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a class to scrape public holiday data, but i would like to iterate my class with many years like :

```
outputt_path = "C:/Users/N000193384/Downloads/countries/"
recent_years = ["2015", "2016", "2017", "2018"]
for year in recent_years : 
    PBC = Event_Scraper("italy", year, outputt_path)
    df = PBC._read_html_()
    df = df.append(df)
```

my class took the country's name and the year, outputt_path is useless there.

_read_html_() builds a cleaned dataframe 
and i would like to append each dataframe.

Here is an example of the dataframe for one year :

```
    Date    Holiday Name    Holiday Type
0   2018-01-01  New Year's Day  National holiday
1   2018-01-06  Epiphany    National holiday
2   2018-03-20  March Equinox   Season
3   2018-03-30  Good Friday Observance
4   2018-04-01  Easter Day  National holiday
```

Comment: Everytime you do a new year... you're rebinding the name `df` to just that year's parsed data and then appending it to itself... So you need to rethink that logic or alternatively put all the DFs into a list, then `pd.concat` them in one go.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a list of dataframes and keep appending new dataframes for each year's data into that list. Once you are done scraping the data you can concat them into one dataframe like this:

```
dfs = []
for year in recent_years : 
    PBC = Event_Scraper("italy", year, outputt_path)
    df = PBC._read_html_()
    dfs.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Appending or doing concat on the dataframe is an expensive operation as Pandas needs to allocate memory for the new dataframe and copy all the data over, so doing it multiple times in a loop will be expensive. Doing it this way saves that overhead as you will only do it once.